# How to create [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]] based on [1,2,3,4,5] by python?

Tags: python

I want to create a structure a list-like structure from a list. Besides knowing how to solve it, I wonder if there is any terminology to describe this process.

More Examples:

```
l = [1,2]
target = [[1,2]]

l = [1,2,3]
target = [[1,2],[1,2,3]]

l = [1,2,3,4]
target = [[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
target = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
target = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

I want to find an approach to get the above structure.

Comment: Please [edit] to include your attempts at the problem and explain the logic of what you're actually trying to do... Have you heard of list slicing?

Comment: WHAT process?  What rules generated that output from that particular input?  Examples with different sizes of input (if there even ARE different possible sizes of input) might help.

Comment: agree with @jasonharper - voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @cricket_007@jasonharper@timgeb I have updated my question. Is it more clear?As a python beginner,  it's my first time to hear list slicing.

Comment: Why is `[1, 2, 3]` not supposed to be part of the result of `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]`? I don't understand the rule you are trying to implement.

Comment: @mkrieger1 In my project, the meaning of `[1,2,3]`  should not be considered . To be more specific, `[1,2,3,4]` should not be considered for  `l  = [1,2,3,4,5]` . I know it's a bit weird.

Comment: I don't understand the rule. Voting to close.

Comment: What should be the result if the input list contains the numbers from `1` to `1000000`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls = ["a","b","c"]
ls2 = [ls[:2],ls[:]]
```

If this is what you are looking for

Comment: I have updated my question. I want to find a general approach to get this.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach:

```
target = []
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(l)):
    value_list = []
    for b in range(i+1):
        target.append(l[:i+1])

print target
```

Recent Edit:

```
target = []
l = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(1, len(l)):
    value_list = []
    for i in range(i+1):
        value_list.append(l[i])
    target.append(value_list)

print target
```

Comment: But it failed in more than three elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python3.4:

```
if len(l)-1 <= 2:
    t = [l[:2+i] for i in range(len(l)-1)]
else:
    t = [l[:2+i] for i in range(len(l)-1)]
    t.pop(-2)

print (t)
```

Based on `Stefan Stefanov` answer, I think this is my general approach.

Comment: And it produces a different result than you specified for `l = [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 After using `if-else` , it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def calculate_result(input_list):
    if input_list == [1,2]:
        target = [1,2]

    elif input_list == [1,2,3]:
        target = [[1,2],[1,2,3]]

    elif input_list == [1,2,3,4]:
        target = [[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]

    elif input_list == [1,2,3,4,5]:
        target = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]

    elif input_list == [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
        target = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

    else:
        raise ValueError('Result for {} not specified.'.format(input_list))

    return target
```

Comment: Not to be taken seriously... :/